# method that takes a hash and returns an array

Tags: arrays, methods, hash, iteration, enumeration

I am trying to build a method that takes two arguments (source, in this case a hash of names, and thing_to_find, in this case an age as an integer) and returns just the hash keys with that integer. The output should be an array of the hash keys with that value (but not output the value).

I'm about fried trying to get this - help very much appreciated. here's what is given...

```
my_family_pets_ages = {"Evi" => 6, "Ditto" => 3, "Hoobie" => 3, "George" => 12, "Bogart" => 4, "Poly" => 4, "Annabelle" => 0}


def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
# here i've tried all manner of has_value?, map, include? etc. - I think I'm probably having a problem with syntax...am I close with this?
   source.select { |k, v| v.include? thing_to_find }
end
```

the output should look like 
    my_hash_finding_method(my_family_pets_ages, 3)
    #=> should return ["Hoobie", "Ditto"]

Comment: I guess this is Ruby syntax. Please say so. Why do you think you have a "syntax problem"? Can you go from your requirements back to see if there is a data structure that helps capture them?

Comment: I'm new so please be gentle.